# Access Libre office headless service of Unix on windows

Tags: java, unix, libreoffice, headless, jodconverter

I am running Libre Office as a headless service on unix machine to convert xlsx files to ods.
JODConverter library is used to connect to service.

The problem occurs when from Windows machine I try to convert the files.
I am getting below exception

```
Caused by: com.sun.star.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported URL <C:%5CUsers%5Cshikhaha%5CDownloads%5CjOpenDocumentTest%5Cone.xlsx>: "from LoadEnv::initializeLoading"
```

The problem seems to be due to file path of windows. Any idea how can I connect to unix service from windows machine.

Thanks,

Hanumant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just dealing with document conversion I would recommend not to run LibreOffice as a service. As of a couple of years ago it had memory leak issues, and required periodic restarts.

I would do a command line document conversion which is pretty fast:

```
$ time soffice --headless --convert-to odt:"calc8" q.xls 
convert /tmp/q.xls -> /tmp/q.odt using calc8

real    0m0.677s
user    0m0.610s
sys 0m0.055s
```

Comment: I assume you are not familiar with JODConverter? The library manages libre office specifically in a way to prevent memory leaks etc from being too big an issue. I have run an openoffice cluster for many years without memory issues.

Comment: @Oleg-Mikheev thanks for your input but since we are already on scheduled plan, diverting from it wont be easy.

Comment: @nablex have you faced similar issue of file path on windows to unix call.

Comment: @hanumant No, the conversions always happened on data already on the server, not on a client pc.

Comment: I didn't know JODConverter. But last activity there was 3-4 years ago, I would avoid it just for that reason :)